# Parse XML Partly

Tags: java, android, parsing, rss, sax

I`m trying to create news app for adnroid. I parse RSS from site. Now i have 200 items, but in future it will be 2000 or more. I use this tutorial to create ListView with Image and Text.
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

But I use different parser.

The problem that i have, it`s - xml file load full. I`m searching the way load and parse partly, by 10-15 items.

For example, at first load 10 items, user scroll down, and load the next 10 items. Is it possible to do it with this parser, or I should use some others: JSON, etc/?

Code:
MAIN ACTIVITY:

```
private NewsParser parser;
private List<PostItem> messages;

parser = new NewsParser();
messages = parser.parse();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
   try
   {
        for (PostItem msg : messages){
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put("Date", msg.getDate());
            map.put("Title", msg.getTitle());
            map.put("Description", msg.getDescription());
            map.put("imgUrl", msg.getImgUrl());

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);
        }
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return menuItems;
```

NewsParser:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.sax.Element;
import android.sax.EndElementListener;
import android.sax.EndTextElementListener;
import android.sax.RootElement;
import android.util.Xml;

public class NewsParser {
    /**
     * We transfer the address bar of RSS feeds in the URL, connect to the server at that address
     * and receive the data stream from the RSS feed.
     * @return
     */
    protected InputStream getInputStream() {
        URL feedUrl = null;
        try {
            feedUrl = new URL("http://www.mysite.com/test_xml");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            return feedUrl.openConnection().getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Parser XML 
     * @return List<PostItem>
     */
    public List<PostItem> parse() {
        final PostItem currentPost = new PostItem();
        final List<PostItem> messages = new ArrayList<PostItem>();
        RootElement root = new RootElement("rss");
        Element channel = root.getChild("channel");
        Element item = channel.getChild("item");
        item.setEndElementListener(new EndElementListener(){
            public void end() {
                messages.add(currentPost.copy());
            }
        });
        item.getChild("title").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener(){
            public void end(String body) {
                currentPost.setTitle(body);
            }
        });
        item.getChild("link").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener(){
            public void end(String body) {
                currentPost.setLink(body);
            }
        });
        item.getChild("description").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener(){
            public void end(String body) {
                currentPost.setDescription(body);
            }
        });
        item.getChild("pubDate").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener(){
            public void end(String body) {
                currentPost.setDate(body);
            }
        });
        item.getChild("imgUrl").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener(){
            public void end(String body) {
                currentPost.setImgUrl(body);
            }
        });
        item.getChild("imgUrlBig").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener(){
            public void end(String body) {
                currentPost.setImgUrlBig(body);
            }
        });
        try {
            Xml.parse(this.getInputStream(), Xml.Encoding.UTF_8, root.getContentHandler());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return messages;
    }
}
```

PostItem:

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class PostItem {
    static SimpleDateFormat FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.US);
    static SimpleDateFormat OUT_FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.US);
    private String title;
    private URL link;
    private String linkText;
    private String description;
    private Date date;
    private String imgUrl;
    private String imgUrlBig;

    /**
     * Setter для title    
     * @param title
     */
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title.trim();
    }
    /**
     * Getter для title
     * @return
     */
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }  
    /**
     * Setter для description
     * @param description
     */
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description.trim();
    }
    /**
     * Getter для description
     * @return
     */
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }   
    /**
     * Setter для link и linkText
     * @param link
     */
    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.linkText = link.trim();
        try {
            this.link = new URL(link);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Getter для link
     * @return
     */
    public URL getLink() {
        return link;
    }
    /**
     * Getter для linkText
     * @return
     */
    public String getLinkText() {
        return linkText;
    }
    /**
     * Setter для date
     * @param date
     */
    public void setDate(String date) {
        try {
            this.date = FORMATTER.parse(date.trim());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }   
    /**
     * Getter для date
     * @return
     */
    public String getDate() {
        return OUT_FORMATTER.format(this.date);
    }
    /**
     * Setter для imgUrl
     * @param imgUrl
     */
    public void setImgUrl(String imgUrl) {
        this.imgUrl = imgUrl.trim();
    }   
    /**
     * Getter для imgUrl
     * @return
     */
    public String getImgUrl() {
        return imgUrl;
    }
    /**
     * Setter для imgUrlBig
     * @param imgUrl
     */
    public void setImgUrlBig(String imgUrlBig) {
        this.imgUrlBig = imgUrlBig.trim();
    }   
    /**
     * Getter для imgUrlBig
     * @return
     */
    public String getImgUrlBig() {
        return imgUrlBig;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(linkText);
        return sb.toString();
    }
    public PostItem copy() {
        PostItem copy = new PostItem();
        copy.title = title;
        copy.link = link;
        copy.linkText = linkText;
        copy.description = description;
        copy.date = date;
        copy.imgUrl = imgUrl;
        copy.imgUrlBig = imgUrlBig;
        return copy;
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you only want to parse part of the xml at a time?

Comment: It will use less traffic and time. Also I try to load 2000 items and the program crashed. If you have any ideas, please tell.